# C#: copying Assets on Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, assets

I try to use Xamarin for the development of an Android app. I built APK but can't get access to Assets where are saved some folders and files.
I need to copy these folders and files from Assets to an application directory of an android device and have access to them any time.

Please, help( I need a simple CSharp function of copy Assets files to an android device. I will grateful for any support.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at  [File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/) and [Using Android Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows) first.

And here is a simple sample :

```
public static async Task CopyFile(Activity activity)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "YOUR_FILENAME");

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fileAssetsStream = activity.Assets.Open("YOUR_FILENAME"))
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];

                int b = buffer.Length;
                int length;

                while ((length = await fileAssetsStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, b)) > 0)
                {
                    await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` [runtime permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows#runtime-permission-checks-in-android-60).

Answer (score 0):

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileCopyingService))]
namespace Mypp.Droid.Services
{
    public class FileCopyingService : IFileCopyingService
    {
        Context _context;
        public FileCopyingService()
        {
            this._context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        }
        public string CopyFiles(string folderName)
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var fileFolder = Path.Combine(path, folderName);
            if (Directory.Exists(fileFolder))
                Directory.Delete(fileFolder, true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fileFolder);

            foreach (var fItemName in this._context.Assets.List(folderName))
            {
                var dbFile = Path.Combine(fileFolder, fItemName);
                if (File.Exists(dbFile))
                {
                    File.Delete(dbFile);
                }
                if (!File.Exists(dbFile))
                {
                    using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(dbFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        var assetsMapFile = folderName + "/" + fItemName;
                        this._context.Assets.Open(assetsMapFile).CopyTo(writeStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            return fileFolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml source

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```